# Is definable bounded separation equivalent to bounded separation?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

If we have all axioms of [Mac Lane set theory](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eardm/maclane.pdf) except Separation and add to them the schema of definable bounded separation, then would the resulting theory be equivalent to Mac Lane set theory?

**Definable bounded Separation:** if $\phi$ is a bounded formula in which all bounds are parameter free definable sets, and if $A$ is a parameter free definable set, then: $\{x \in A \mid \phi\}$ exists.

To write this in full, let $\psi_0,..,\psi_n$ be formulas such that each $\psi_i$ only have symbol $x_i$ occuring free; let $\phi$ be a formula not using symbol $X$ and in which all quantifiers appear as "$\in B_i$" bounded, then:

$\forall A, B_1,..,B_n \\ A= \{x_0 \mid \psi_0\}, B_1=\{x_i \mid \psi_i\},.., B_n=\{x_n \mid \psi_n\} \\ \implies \exists X: X=\{x \in A \mid \phi\}$

Comment: Is this theory equivalent to KP-Foundation-Collection but with separation replaced with definable-bounded separation?

Comment: @C7X, why exclude Foundation? It is there.

Comment: I didn't see foundation or regularity on the list on the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory#Connection_with_standard_set_theory, if so should this page be edited?

Comment: @C7X, Thanks for drawing my attention to this point. I attached an article speaking about the original system of Mac Lane, it does contain foundation.

Comment: This may not be enough to post as a full answer, but I believe most countable models of KP are also pointwise definable. According to Marek and Srebrny's thesis "Gaps in the Constructible Universe", if $\alpha$ isn't during a gap then $L_\alpha$ is pointwise definable. For non-gap $\alpha$ modeling KP-Collection, we have $L_\alpha$ models KP-Collection-Sep+Definable-bounded-sep, and there since the model is pointwise definable we have definable-boudned sep equivalent to separation.